# Text editor to colour code rich text format (Rtf) commands

Tags: colors, notepad++, language, styles, rtf

Is there a program which can read and colour code Rtf code in its text editor? Notepad++ supports the coloring of many languages such as C++ or Javascript, but Rtf isn't supported (it's not exactly a language, but even so).

This one's a tricky one to research because a search in Google for "Rtf editor" will return editors which save to that format, rather than work with it in its raw code-like form.

Answer (score 1):

`vim` supports syntax highlighting for`.rtf` files.
It's available on quite a few platforms, including [Windows](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc).

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, and although text is distinguished, all the control words are the same colour (only 2-3 colours total). Maybe there's something better...

Comment: @DanW Last time I checked, language elements of the same type (type names, keywords, etc.) are colored the same way in most editors.